# Inner product and Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, real-numbers

> [[...]with an inner product $(x,y)$, $x,y∈\mathbb{R}^n$, which in a suitably chosen (Cartesian) coordinate system $x=(x_1,…,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,…,y_n)$ is given by the formula $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Euclidean_space)

What does Encyclopedia mean by saying "in a suitably chosen (Cartesian) coordinate system"? Isn't the formula true without referency to any coordinate system?

Comment: Suitable = orthonormal. As a counter-example, consider a 2D plane with "skew" axes: then the inner product is not according to the given formula.

Comment: If we are treating Euclidean space as a set with three operations defined on it, why do we even care about the coordinate systems? It's just tuples of real numbers with operations, which don't seem to depend on the geometric interpretation (I'm using the definition of coordinate system as a system assigning the tuples to points in space), defined on it. Let's say I choose two elements from $\mathbb{R}^n$ and want to perform this operation, without reference to geometry, treating it simply as an operation on numbers like addition or multiplication, to get a real number. Why can't I?

Comment: You can pick any coordinate system and define some function as $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$ but would it satisfy the definition of an inner product ?

Comment: What's the definition? I have seen it as saying that it's a function satisfying certain properties, but is it unique? What's the general formula of the function? If we are saying that Euclidean space is $((\mathbb{R}^n,+,*),i)$ with $i$ being the inner product, we seem to be speaking about a certain unique object.

Comment: You can take a general definition and show that in any orthonormal basis it is expressed (invariantly) by the given sum, or if your interest is more confined to the geometry and physics of $R^3$ you can define it as the given sum in an orthonormal basis and then show that it is invariant under orthogonal transformations to a different orthonormal basis.

Comment: To simplify what you may have read, in a real vector space ($R^n$) an inner product <., .> is a mapping which satisfies (1) <x, x> is $\ge 0$ for all x and = 0 only if x = 0; (2) <x + y, z> = <x, z> + <y, z>; (3) <a.x, y> = a<x, y>; (4) <x, y> = <y, x>, You can easily show that the given sum in an orthonormal basis satisfies these conditions. The proof that a function satisfying these conditions is expressed by the given sum in any orthonormal basis is somewhat more involved, but it is true.

Comment: So non-orthonormal bases have different objects as their inner products than orthonormal ones. I suppose that they don't give the same results as the "Cartesian" product. Is this correct? What's more, since Euclidean spaces are a class of objects with an inner product, a space with non-orthonormal basis is another Euclidean space than a one with it, with possibly different solutions to inner product?

Comment: Adding to the above, can there be a coordinate system allowing for more than a single inner product?

Comment: The inner product is best regarded as a property of two vectors independent of the co-ordinate system. It may add to your insight to consider expressing the usual inner product of 3D vectors in terms of spherical polar co-ordinates (it isn't   $\Sigma \theta_x \theta_y + \phi_x \phi_y + r_x r_y$).